# after jenv uninstall each command prints "command not found: jenv", how to get rid of that?

Tags: java, homebrew, jenv

My mac has everything installed using brew. I also had `jenv` installed. I got frustrated with

> "jvisualvm The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports jvisualvm",

decided to uninstall everything. Uninstalled `java`, uninstalled `jenv`.

Now even `ls` command prints

> "jenv:11: command not found: jenv".

How to get rid of this message?
I did remove jenv lines from `~/.zshrc` and `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Have you restarted the shell session? Also, what if you try to search for jenv in your home dir like <grep -i jenv .>

Comment: restarting shell session worked. Can you suggest proper way to install openjdk8 on Mac? With brew install, jvisualvm didn't work. "jvisualvm The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports jvisualvm"

Comment: Use https://sdkman.io best one out there for managing Java versions and others

Comment: It has same issues. Jvisualvm throws same error.

Comment: Have you checked the troubleshoot guide of VisualVM? There plenty of things to check there related to it not working. Here: https://visualvm.github.io/documentation.html

Comment: Well, I couldn't run the jvisualvm that comes with jdk but separate installation of visualvm works fine. Thanks @JorgeCampos